# Android external storage encryption

Tags: android, encryption, storage

I want to know how to encrypt the external storage data (.asec).
Which algorithm is used, AES or another method?
And then what is the encryption key?
If a method to generate encryption key is open source, I think that it is going to cause a problem. 
I would be grateful for any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Open Source Project provides a document [describing their crypto implementation](http://source.android.com/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html).

Basically, they use AES in the Linux DM-CRYPT layer. See the document for full details, including how it interacts with `vold`.